# Use of Handler in Single Threaded application

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

According to Android Documentation

> "A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is
>   associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When
>   you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of
>   the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver
>   messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they
>   come out of the message queue."

I totally get the use of Handler in Multi-Threaded application, in which one thread will post to other thread message queue using Handler, but what is the use of Handler in single threaded application. The reason why I am asking this is because I saw couple of sample applications at developer.google.com using HAndler in single threaded application. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/index.html) is one example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a multi-threaded use, because it shows the handler being used in an AsyncTask. But even so, the example says multiple times in the comments that they're using the handler to update the UI (presumably from the Service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example you posted is not single threaded - for example the doInBackground() method of an AsyncTask runs on a thread separate from the UI thread. That is why a Handler is being called in that method.

Read up on AsyncTasks and then look at the ReverseGeocodingTask in your sample.

Comment: My bad. I did saw AsyncTask but I did not paid attention to the fact that, because of AsyncTask Handler is used. I got confused as message was also sent from setup() which is called from onResume(). Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: No problem. The threading model in Android can get a little tricky.